# How to use open() a file in osx so that other threads can't remove it?

Tags: macos, file, locking

I want to implement a file level locking in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short:

```
fd = open( "./foo", O_RDWR + O_EXLOCK);
```

But you first need to check if your fs supports it, see [Exclusive File Access in Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn/tn2037.html). If not, you can lock 'by convention', using for example a lock file. This is explained in the article.